# php loop and <a> tag to go to another page

Tags: php, loops, foreach, clickable

Hi I have searched a lot to find a solution but still have  problem. I have created foreachloop to check selected item and bring them on the main page and it works perfectly but after that I want the brought image to be clickable and go to another page that indicates more details of that image. the image is clickable now but does not go any where. here is parts of my code:

[image]

Comment: This is something that will need to be done in JavaScript, not PHP. You already have `.photo`; just hook up an event listener to that.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of post. Post the code itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw that you put in href only the **$id**

```
<a href="productsByItemId.php?id=<?= $id ?>">
```

And the right thing is **$itemId**

```
<a href="productsByItemId.php?id=<?= $itemId ?>">
```

Comment: Many thanks u saved my life Do not know how to appreciate